# Signed Addition overflow in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I tried to implement and addition of two signed numbers. The first one is 32 bit and the second one is also 32 bit, but correspond the addition of the earlier operation. The code VHLD is below :

```
Entity Sum_Position is 
  port 
  (
     Clk: in std_logic;
     Reset: in std_logic;
     Raz_position: in std_logic;
     Position_In: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
     Position_Out: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
  );
end Sum_Position;


Architecture Arch_position of sum_Position is 

    -- create locale signals
    signal position_before: signed (31 downto 0):= (OTHERS => '0');
    -- both signals have one more bit than the original
    signal Position_s   : SIGNED(Position_In'length downto 0):= (OTHERS => '0');
    signal Position_Before_s   : SIGNED(Position_In'length downto 0):= (OTHERS => '0');
    signal Sum_Pos_s : SIGNED(Position_In'length downto 0):= (OTHERS => '0');

    Begin  -- begin of architecture

     -- convert type and perform a sign-extension
    Position_s <=SIGNED(Position_In(31) & Position_In);
    Position_Before_s<=resize(signed(position_before), Position_Before_s'length);

    Sum_of_position: process(Clk, Reset) 

    begin 

       IF (Reset='0') THEN          -- when reset is selected
           -- initialize all values 
          Sum_Pos_s<= (OTHERS => '0');
       ELSIF (Clk'event and Clk = '1') then
           -- addition of two 33 bit values
          Sum_Pos_s <= Position_s + Position_Before_s;

       END IF;  

    end process Sum_of_position;

    -- resize to require size and type conversion
    position_before <= (OTHERS => '0') WHEN Raz_position='1' else 
                        signed(resize(Sum_Pos_s, position_before'length));

    -- Resize and output the result
    Position_Out  <= (OTHERS => '0') WHEN Raz_position='1' else  
                     std_logic_vector(resize(Sum_Pos_s, Position_Out'length));

    end Arch_position;
```

But, i have overflow because the result is very strange. Can you please suggest me a solution?

Best regards;

Comment: Most importantly, you don't say what the strange behaviour is. What happens? What did you expect to happen? You could help those helping you by providing an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): how about simplifying the code (it seems to be a 32-bit accumulator) and providing a testbench?

Comment: This is the image [enter image description here](http://i.stack.imgur.com/021Uc.png) test after simulation, the result is not as expected

Comment: @Matthew: Thank for you answer. By strange behavior, i mean that when i add to value, the result is not the expected one.

Comment: My point is that it is going to take someone quite a bit of time to understand your code, work out what output should be expected and then to compare it with the output that ought to be expected. Part of that work would be to generate a testbench. You are more likely to find an answer if you create the testbench, if you give some results and specifically point out which ones are wrong and how and if you simplify your code. There is particular magic about simplifying code: quite often you spot what the problem is yourself in the act of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code is quite unclear.

Secondly, there is no reason for position_before(_s) to be asynchronous, it should be clocked, e.g. (summarized):

```
begin 
   IF (Reset='0') THEN          -- when reset is selected
       -- initialize all values 
      Sum_Pos_s<= (OTHERS => '0');
   ELSIF (Clk'event and Clk = '1') then
      Position_Before_s <= Sum_Pos_s
      Sum_Pos_s <= Position_s + Position_Before_s;
   END IF;  
end process Sum_of_position;
```

Thirdly, the answer to your question. You pass floats to your VHDL engine. Interprete them as signed and add them. You should look at IEEE754 floats. There is a fixed field for the sign bit, one for the exponent and one for the mantissa. You can't just add everything up.

Step 1 is to express both on the same exponent basis. Then add the adjusted mantissas and keep the exponent. Then rescale the mantissa for the most significant bit to correspond to 0.5.

What you to is the following:
0.4 + 40 = (0.1) * 4 + (10) * 4 
mantissas are both 4
exponents are -1 and 1. without fields overflowing, your result becomes an exponent of 0 and a mantissa of 8, so 8.

Comment: Float is overkill. It requires a lot of extra logic in implementation and often has a longer latency (unless you properly pipeline your design)

Answer (score 0):

Most modern VHDL tools have `Integer` types (`signed` and `unsigned`).
These are usually 32 bits wide unless you use the `Range` modifier.

I suggest you consider using integers rather than `std_logic_vector`.

You can convert between types like casts in C.

This is my favourite diagram on casting/ converting VHDL types. I have printed it out and put it on my wall http://www.bitweenie.com/listings/vhdl-type-conversion

A page in integers in VHDL http://vhdl.renerta.com/mobile/source/vhd00039.htm

Comment: Hmm. Have you noticed this is a 1 year old question. I doubt the TS is still struggling with this issue. Furthermore, please don't use links in your answer. Links tend to expire, making the answers possibly useless for future reference. Finally, using the `integer`type in VHDL also has a big downside: it is fixed signed and has no overflow handling. I.e. in this case the TS wants to add two 32 bit signed values: if they are both near the integer maximum, you will get an unhandled overflow.

Comment: ...For values larger then 32 bit, `integer`is useless, and for values smaller, synthesis well still implement 32 bit logic. I would not advice use of integer without a range limit.

Comment: I did not notice the date. Synthesis does implement other bit widths correctly with the RANGE option.  I use this all the time.